# Typescript: type '{}' has no index signature

Tags: typescript

I want to write a function to substitute fields in a template with a series of values. The fields in the string template has the form `{keyname}`. The code is as follows:

```
function replaceAll(template:string, values:object) {
  Object.keys(values).map((e) => {
    const key = new RegExp("{" + e + "}", "g");
    template = template.replace(key, values[e]);  //xxx
  });
  return template;
}

let result = replaceAll("the {q} brown {f}...", { q: "quick", f: "fox"});
```

Unfortunately this code won't compile. At `values[e]` at xxx, it gives:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature.
>
> (parameter) values: object

What does the error message mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: `object` isn't an [indexable type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types), so `values[e]` gets typed as `any`.

Comment: `values` should probably be a dict or an array, not just an object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following type: `{ [key: string]: string }`, naturally changing `string` to whatever may be passed in as the key and value, respectively.

You're receiving the error message because when you access the value of the object, it doesn't know what type it should be, and is therefore implicitly any. You can, of course, still have a value that is *explicitly* any, but you'll still need to use something like the example I gave.

Comment: What does the square brackets in `{ [key: string]: string}` mean?

Comment: @OldGeezer The key is a string, as is the value.

Comment: What I meant was aren't square brackets used to represent arrays?

Comment: @OldGeezer it's an object. That's how keys are represented, as an array can't be a key, while the literal "string" could be.