# Set optional header into class in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

```
export default class ErrorResponseModel {
    body: string
    headers: object
    statusCode: number

    constructor(message: object, statusCode: number = 500, header?: {key: string, value: string}) {
        this.headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        this.body = JSON.stringify(message)
        this.statusCode = statusCode

        if (header) {
            this.headers[header.key] = header.value
        }

    }
}
```

I try to set header into `this.headers`, but get an error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.\n  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.
```

How can I deal with this error? I use TypeScript v4.7.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a record for headers instead: `headers: Record<string, string>`. See [Typescript: type '{}' has no index signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51214575/typescript-type-has-no-index-signature)